# Minimum degree of separation using ranking lists as edges

Tags: graph-theory, programming, network

**TL;DR:** I want to find the minimum path from a node $X$ to a node $Y$ in a directed graph. But the edges aren't directly given: There are some rankings (ordered lists of nodes), and there is a directed edge from the node $A$ to node $B$ if and only if there is a ranking where $A$ is placed above $B$. Is there a algorithm for that, or a name of this kind of dense graphs, with "ranking-like" edges? Is this a known problem? Are there good heuristics?

---

Context of the problem + What I've been thinking: suppose that were was a game, skill-based, where a lot (around ~100k) of participants take place in each round, and at the end of each round there is a ranking with all participants sorted based on how well they performed on it. Not all players of this game take part on each round - Actually, just a small fraction of them.

Naturally, there are some players who are really good at it (as it isn't luck-based), so they always take the top positions. I was wondering how, given $A$ and $B$, I could find a chain $C_1, C_2, C_3\ ..., C_n$ of participants such that $A$ has performed better than $C_1$ in some round, $C_n$ has performed better than $B$ in some round, and $\forall\ 1 \le i < n$, $C_i$ has performed better than $C_{i+1}$ in some round. Additionally, I wanted that chain to be the smallest possible. But I can't just do a standard graph searching algorithm as a BFS on it, because the number of edges would be too huge - $O(K\cdot N^2)$, where $K$ is the number of rounds and $N$ is the number of participants in each round, because each ranking would lead to $O(N^2)$ edges.

I didn't had many progress towards it, mainly because I don't know the terminology to that stuff. One of the things I thought was a heuristic algorithm: I assign a "ELO" to each participant based on their mean performance. Then, I find a path from $X$ to a higher ELO, and from there, it should be easier to get to $Y$. But I'm interested in knowing better heuristics (not sure if deterministic algorithms would be fast enough). This is really, really close to [six degrees of separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation#An_optimal_algorithm_to_calculate_degrees_of_separation_in_social_networks), but the main difference is the amount of the edges involved, I think.